# fancyBox with AJAX loaded content is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2

I'm trying to get [fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) (FB from now on) working and can't get it. I'll explain below what I do. The first is, of course, include the FB scripts and styles as follow:

```
<!-- fancyBox styles -->
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css" rel="stylesheet">

<!-- fancyBox JS -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js"></script>
<script src="/app_dev.php/js/bmain_registro_2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

In my HTML code I have this:

```
<a href="#" class="getregistered">Register</a>
<div id="register"></div>
```

It's empty because the content is loaded trough AJAX call made on `bmain_registro_2.js` as you'll see below. Then in `bmain_registro_2.js` I write this:

```
var $register = $("#register");

if ($register.length) {
    $register.load(Routing.generate('datos-basicos'));
}

$("#tabs").tabs();

$('.getregistered').on("click", function() {
    console.log("click");
    $("#register").fancybox({
        openEffect: 'elastic',
        closeEffect: 'elastic',
        autoSize: false,
        closeClick: false
    });
});
```

`Routing.generate('datos-basicos')` comes from Symfony2 and FOSJsRoutingBundle but it's working fine because I get the content I want to show on the modal. The problems?

- The modal content isn't hide (see the image below) and I think should be hide by default

[image]

- When I click on `Register` link the `console.log()` code is executed but the modal never show up

What I'm missing here and is my code right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the 'fancybox' class to the link as following:
`<a href="#" class="fancybox" >Register</a>`
Regards..